# Add pages to dynamic routes on runtime Next Js

Tags: reactjs, routes, seo, next.js

So I am working on a simple next js application A Blog System. So like a basic blog, I have a posts section where I see all my posts that i have ever posted.

The post page is a dynamic route named

```
/posts/title-of-the-post
```

So i used a `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` for extracting the title and fetching the data from the mongodb database. It is all working great.

But I have another route called

```
/posts/add-new
```

that adds a new post to my database and my readers can see these. So the function is working and when I create a new post it is saved in the database but when I try to access it with url of `posts/new-post-url` I get 404 Not Found error.

I can pretty much understand that the dynamic pages and paths are build on runtime so when I add a new page, it is not in the build folder so 404.

But how to solve it. What I want is the ability to add new pages in my blog and they should be SEO friendly and visible to user. Just like how I posted this question on stack overflow and it will now be accessible by the url and after some time it will take the top spot in google search.

Please help. Thank YOu in advance :(   ->   :|   ->   :)

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to add new pages without rebuilding an app with +150k static pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66036558/how-to-add-new-pages-without-rebuilding-an-app-with-150k-static-pages)? Use `fallback: 'blocking'` inside `getStaticPaths` to allow generating new pages that weren't generated during build time.

Answer (score 1):

Next.JS provides 3 options for serving content.
[SSG Static Site Generator](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props) - it builds pages once and serves pregenerated content.
[ISG Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration) - it allows you to regenerate static pages under certain conditions.
[SSR Server Side Rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) - server will generate a page per request.

For blog SSG would be the better choice: posts usually don’t change or changes rarely.
You should use the `fallback` setting in `getStaticPaths`. You have to set `fallback` to `true` or `'blocking'`.

`true` - the new paths will serve as a fallback on the first request, while Next.JS will be generating the page. Then it will swap the fallback to the actual content.
`'blocking'` - the new paths will be blocked until the page is generated.

For both options, all subsequent requests will serve the pre-generated page.

Keep in my for long building pages you can get a timeout error. By default, it’s 60 seconds, but you always can tune it by `staticPageGenerationTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the fresh data, set `revalidate:1` in `getStaticProps` and `fallback:true` in `getStaticPaths`. Check the example below

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // make a get request to server to see how many blogs are there
  const json = await new BlogApi().getAll();
  // assuming using axios
  const blogs = json.data;
  const paths = blogs.map(blog => {
    return {
      params: {id: blog._id}
    }
  })
  // fallback is used to display some content while your content is beign prepared
  return { paths, fallback: true };
}

export async function getStaticProps({params}) {
  const json = await new BlogApi().getById(params.id);
  const portfolio = json.data;
  return { props: {portfolio}, revalidate: 1};
}
```

In your component, if `fallback:true`

```
const router = useRouter();

  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <h1>Your page is being preapared</h1>
  }
```